# Is it possible to extract the subject of an image and compare it for a match with another image?

Tags: ios, machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision

I want to make an app that can look for the subject of an image and compare it with other photos I've taken for a match. For example:

- I take a picture of an iPad sitting on a brown table.
- I take a picture of the same iPad sitting on a different surface.
- I want to be able to detect if the iPads in the two photos are actually the same iPad.
- If I take a photo of an iPhone I don't want it to match.
- But I do want it match if it looks the same as in the other image.

I recognize that this is a broad topic, but I'm wondering what tools might be available for use on iOS.

I have looked into Apple's image recognition and ML libraries, but those seem more geared toward identifying what an object is, not whether two objects are a match.

Comment: how do you define the subject? does it have to autodetect the subject ? or you can choose the subject region and it detects for same subject in all other images?

Answer (score 0):

They added the ability to do 3d object recognition in ArKit with iOS 12.  Basically you scan the object from several angles with the app and in generates a bunch of anchors and a file.  Recognizing the object in your AR app is as easy as setting the objects you want to detect on your ARSession configuration.  I tried scanning a coke can and then recognizing it and placing a spinning cube on top of it and it worked pretty well.  The apple sample is well documented and it requires very little code to accomplish since the framework does all of the heavy lifting.

See Apple's sample project and explanation here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/scanning_and_detecting_3d_objects